# Recurring timeframes in careers profile?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd like to be able to input the following value in my careers profile:

> June 2008 - September 2008, June 2009 - September 2009,  June 2010 - September 2010

Even better would be:

> Fall 2008, 2009, 2010

I've got some experience which, to be honest, doesn't look good repeated three times, but is just fine when condensed.

Can this be added to the date parser?

Comment: Was just about to ask this question myself ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look like summer jobs. If you indicate in the body that they were summer job and then just list them from June 2008 - September 2010 then almost every employer (the ones you care about at least) will understand that you didn't do them from Sept - June every year.